# Javascript Webworker how to put json information into array buffer

Tags: javascript, string, arraybuffer

I have thousands of small strings that I have to pass from a webworker back to the main page, each one is something like this:

```
"this string needs to be sent"
```

How would I be able to include it into an array buffer in order to increase the transfer speed? I understand how to use numbers with array buffers, but how do you use strings? I am looking for something like this:

```
var strings = ["str1","str2","str3",...]
for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    arraybuffer[i] = //Whatever operation works to add strings[i]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth measuring and comparing performance of various techniques. The worker could use [SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) if supported in your target browsers (not exemplified below), otherwise [Transferrable objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Transferable_objects) can be used with `postMessage()`. [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) creates ArrayBuffers from strings.

Individual strings can be transferred as they are encoded:

```
const encoder = new TextEncoder()
strings.forEach(s => {
  const encoded = encoder.encode(s)
  postMessage(encoded, [encoded.buffer])
})
```

An array of strings could be transferred in batches:

```
const encoded = strings.map(s => encoder.encode(s))
postMessage(encoded, encoded.map(bytes => bytes.buffer))
```

Comment: Are there any special browser settings that have to be enabled for sharedarraybuffer? I tried using it on ms edge version 96, which is supposed to be supported, and it did not work.

Comment: [Requires cross-origin isolation](https://caniuse.com/sharedarraybuffer) • [SharedArrayBuffer updates](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70535752/enable-sharedarraybuffer-on-localhost/70536119#70536119) to quickly test `SharedArrayBuffer`