# Enable SharedArrayBuffer on localhost

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, webassembly, arraybuffer, sharedarraybuffer

I keep getting a 'SharedArrayBuffer is not defined' error when trying to run ffmpeg.wasm. It appears this is on the Webassembly side. Regardless, I know this is an issue that can be overcome with Cross Origin Isolation. However, I'm trying to run it on a local host, which from what I understand Cross Origin Isolation wouldn't help. I tried following the instructions at the bottom of this [guide](https://web.dev/cross-origin-isolation-guide/) but to no avail. I've also tried an approach of changing the Chrome//flags but that didn't work either. I just need to be able to run ffmpeg/wasm in the browswer but having a bit of trouble. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you sort this out?

Comment: I'm the author of [the guide at web.dev](https://web.dev/cross-origin-isolation-guide/#:~:text=--enable-features%3Dsharedarraybuffer). I'm interested how it didn't work for you. Can you tell me in more details?

Answer (score 4):

The localhost server should provide the required response headers:

```
$ curl -I http://localhost/

Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
```

This server script provides a baseline test for `SharedArrayBuffer` availability:

```js
// $ node server.mjs

import { createServer } from 'http'

createServer((request, response) => {
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf8',
    'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin',
    'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy': 'require-corp',
  })
  response.write(`<script>
    document.write(window.SharedArrayBuffer
      ? '✅ SAB available'
      : '❌ SAB unavailable'
    )
  </script>`)
  response.end()
}).listen(80)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a page cross-origin isolated by serving the page with these response headers:

```
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

If you use NGINX as proxy, you just add the following code to the location block where you want to add the header::

```
location some-location {
  add_header "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy" "same-origin";
  add_header "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy" "require-corp";     
}
```

Or more simpler, you can use token from this [page](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/#origin-trial) to enable SharedArrayBuffer without requiring the page to be cross-origin isolated. However, it has an expiration date.

In your web page, you only need to add following tag into tag

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="{token}">
</head>
```

And if you use NGINX, please add header

```
add_header Origin-Trial {token};
```